# IBM FileNet 5.2 - Visibility by security

Tags: filenet-p8, filenet-content-engine, filenet

I'm curious about the "issue" in the title. Let's assume that I have a document with groups "A", "B" assigned to it. Then once I log in, as the user of group "C" in the APP, that document will show up or hidden automatically by FileNet Content Engine logic?

What you think based on your experience. By past experience, if I recall it does that thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my issue was. Working with Custom Object which contains "Security Proxy" class with security ldap configurations.

So, in order to change inheritance of an document class, I had to replace an old security proxy with a new one. And uola...that did a trick.

Answer (score 0):

I can see documents in acce search, documents I don't have access to. But I see the documents and their properties. Not their permissions though.

It might depend on the permissions the user has on the object store.

Comment: Well, at this point no one had similar issues on development through FileNet APIs. I'll investigate on my own... :-)